# Empty HttpContext when calling WCF webservice

Tags: wcf, silverlight, web-services

I recently wrote a webservice to be used with Silverlight which uses the ASP.net membership and roles.

To validate the client in the service I look at the HTTPContext.Current.User (Which works when the service is called from Silverlight)

However, I've been trying to call the same service from an asp.net postback. But when I step-thru to the service the HTTPContext.Current has an emplty string for the username.

I'm guessing there is something that I'm not doing in the web.config file which is causing the httpContext to not be sent through the proxy to my service?

Any ideas would be appreciated. I need to be able to validate the client somehow using asp.net membership and roles and have it work from both an asp.net client and a silverlight client.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about where the ASP.NET calls are coming from? Is it in the same context as the service? Are you forcing them to log in to the site before hitting the service?

Comment: They log in on the site (although they can browse without logging in) I call the service during a postback. I can look at the HttpContext in the postback which is populated with the logged in user. But on the service side the HttpContext is empty.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean by the same context, the service is being hosted in a different place to the application if that is what you mean.

Comment: I have enabled asp compatability in the web.config of the service. But my security mode in the bindings is set to none, could this be a problem where it's not sending the credentials?

Comment: How are they logging into the service from Silveright? Can you post the steps the two clients go through? Sorry, but I'm still not totally clear on what you're doing here.

Comment: I followed the steps in this video to set it up to work for Silverlight http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=56228

Comment: If I understand your previous clarification correctly, the Silverlight client is not calling the WCF Web Service directly. You mention that you are calling the Web Service from an ASP.NET post back, is this correct?

Comment: The Silverlight project has the webservice hosted under its silverlight.web project and the asp.net client is calling the service from an asp.net postback. Yup.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it!

Looks like by default the Silverlight application was sending all the browsers cookies to the service. One of these cookies is the ".ASPXAUTH" cookie to authenticate against the membership and roles.

The asp.net application however was not sending the cookies to the service. To send the authorisation cookie I used the following code before calling my webservice method.

```
    using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(ws.InnerChannel))
    {
HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequest);

            HttpCookieCollection cc = Page.Request.Cookies;
            if (Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies[".ASPXAUTH"];
                String authcookieValue = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
                httpRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie: " + ".ASPXAUTH=" + authcookieValue);

            }
// Webservice call goes here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of HTTPContext try ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity

Comment: ServiceSecurityContext is null - Although I do have <security mode="None"/> For the service, maybe I have to setup certificates or something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it is working from Silverlight but not ASP.Net, but for starters here is a good [blog post on how to setup WCF to work with ASP.Net membership providers](http://nayyeri.net/blog/use-asp-net-membership-and-role-providers-in-windows-communication-foundation/). There are quite a few steps so this could be pretty easy to miss a setting.

Once you get that working correctly then I imagine both should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because my wcf service is in my silverlight.web project, and perhaps they are more friendly when it comes to sharing.

I may need to read up more on wcf and create a greater seperation of concerns by setting up a seperate webservice project?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Ok I've taken a look at the HTTP Post request using Fiddler

Looks like the Silverlight App is sending a 'State' with an authorization cookie and my asp.net app isn't.

Looks like I need to send the state + my authorization cookie when I call the service. I may need to formulate a new question soon...